# What was the significance of the books exchanged between Spud and The Guv?

Tags: analysis, reference, spud

In the film *Spud*, The Guv used to give books to Spud and there were constant references of these books. I can only spot and understand the reference of *The Lord of the Rings* which he even related with himself as a Hobbit.

But what were the rest of the books exchanged and what was their importance for the moment? Is this explained in the novel?